# php post issue in webform ( system command )

Tags: php, forms, post, output

i would like to create a form in my webapp ( penetration testing ) , that asks for a target and some options , then take those parameters and execute a system command that run a ruby file in the same directory . in the following format ' ruby file.rb -u $target $option'  , and output the result , thank you
this is the form that i created and dident work

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
Target: <input type="text" name="target"><br>
<input type="submit">
<select name="taskOption">
  <option>First</option>
  <option>Second</option>
  <option>Third</option>
</select>
</form>
```

and this is test.php

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

$last_line = system('ruby file.rb -u $target $option', $retval);

// Printing additional info
echo "$retval"
?>
```

Comment: Go for it. If you have problems in the process, come back in ask, but we're not here to do it for you.

Comment: tell us what you have tried by posting your code

Comment: actually my friend , i did

Comment: Well your project is very understandable to you, but when you post your code we will understand the logic of it. Thats why we asking for it

Comment: like i sad , the user will put the target and an option , i want to execute the file.rb $target $option and show the output

Comment: what's $target and $retval?

Comment: $target is what the user will write in the text box , and $retval is nothing just me testing

Comment: do you have any if(isset($_POST['submit'])){} olso from where $retval is getting it;s value?

Comment: just delete $retval , tell what i need to put in the form and in the other php file that's it man dont make it hard for me

Comment: You need to study. You are trying to run before you know how to walk

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

info.php

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
Target: <input type="text" name="target"><br>
<input type="submit">
<select name="option">
  <option>First</option>
  <option>Second</option>
  <option>Third</option>
</select>
</form>
```

test.php

```
<?php
$retval= "test";
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
                $$k = $v;                       
                }

$last_line = system('ruby file.rb -u $target $option', $retval);

// Printing additional info
echo $retval."<br>";//will echo test
echo "Target: ".$target ." option: ". $option;
?>
```

i believe this will help

//old answer
I believe you have to assign the post data to variables 
also you will have to rename your "taskOption" to "option"

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
                // edit: dont use that part, since you don't have a mysql connection$r = mysql_real_escape_string($v);
                $$k = $v; //$r;                     
                }
```

Comment: this will go to which file ? and if you would please tell me the function of this

Comment: to test.php it is use to capture all $_post data that you have submitted, assigning the value to the variable name, that's why i've advised you to change the name of your select.

Comment: my problem is i am a python developer , can't you please , and this will be very very kind of you , if you can give me the full info.php and test.php files ? i woul love if you do that please

Comment: can you pleace contact me fb.com/ceh.tn